# how can i make this bubblesort in java work

Tags: java

```
int[] array = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("[" + array[x] + "] ");
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {

            for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {

                if (array[y] > array[x]) {

                    int temp = array[x];
                    array[y] = array[x];
                    array[x] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("[" + array[x] + "] ");

        }
```

can someone tell me why this bubblesort is not working? cant find my mistake.

help would be appreciated

Comment: Your swap is incorrect. You're effectively setting both `array[x]` and `array[y]` to `array[x]`.

Comment: `int temp = array[y];` also `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

Comment: thx guys! appreciate it

Comment: The outer loop "for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) " is good to start from "x = 1", you don't need to start from "x=0"

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of bubblesort seems okay. The issue is in your swap functionality, you can tell this because you are duplicating values. You are setting the temp variable to array[x] and then setting array[y] to array[x] then setting array[x] to temp. So in the end array[x] = array[x] and array[y] = array[x]. The simple fix is changing your temp to be temp = array[y]